# Adding Minicart to custom header results in a empty cart in magento 2

Tags: magento2, phtml, knockoutjs, mini-cart

I tried adding the mini cart phtml to my header like this

```
<?php  echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar')->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

And the **icon appears but the cart appears empty** while there most certainly is something added in the cart.

[image]

my best guess is that I need to add some javascript file to show the information. would anybody know what to add to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the file `app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` you'll see there is more involved than just creating the block:

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
                <container name="minicart.addons" label="Mini-cart promotion block"/>
            </block>
```

There are also lots of different layout updates that are applied.

You might be best off making part of your header include a container named `header-wrapper` which is where the minicart is put. You may also need a header block named `head.components` which loads in another template possibly related to the minicart.

Comment: Thanks man! I restructured my header and after that it works :)